# PKI Protected Web Service. Getting HTTP 413: Request entity too large

Tags: .net, web-services, pki, encryption-asymmetric, client-certificates

I have been trying to implement a secure way to authenticate web servers which are calling a .Net SOAP based web service via security certificates.

I have setup a certificate authority on the receiving server, allowing me to issue a certificate that we have installed on the receiving server and on the calling server. I have also added this certificate authority as a trusted authority on the calling server's  certificate root store.

The problem I am having right now is that when I set IIS to "require" a certificate, I can only send a small dataset, 25 rows at a time, with about 25 fields per row, maybe 100 chars long each. The data I am sending is already encrypted with a symmetric key. When I remove the requirement for a client certificate the amount of data I can send becomes about 25000 rows. When do this with the client certificate "required", I get

> HTTP 413: Request entity too large

My best guess is that the requirement turns on asymmetric encryption both ways, making the amount of data grow exponentially. I have tried modifying the web.config, specifically

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"  maxRequestLength="20000000" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

but this seems to have no effect, even when sending 50 rows in a dataset.

I would also like to add

```
maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="100000"
```

but I am not sure where it goes.

I send the client certificate using

```
Dim S as new webmethodname.webmethod
Dim x509 As X509Certificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("filelocation")
            s.ClientCertificates.Add(x509)
```

The two solutions I can think of are

1. Raise the data limit even more or find the field limit that’s
   stopping me
2. Send smaller batches at a time.
3. Abandon use of client certificates for this purpose and seek another solution.

Any advice on the proper way to do this, or information on what exactly is happening behind the scenes from server to server using SSL and PKI would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you set IIS to require certificate?

Comment: I set it under the application level instead of the website level, this was causing most of my problems with sending data.